# Display all Icons of a pack

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display every icons of my custom_icons.dart file. So I need to get all of them in a list but I don't know how to. Here is a piece of the file

```
class Custom {


Custom._();

  static const _kFontFam = 'Custom';

  static const IconData restaurant_menu = const IconData(0xe800, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
  static const IconData food = const IconData(0xe801, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
  static const IconData chart_line = const IconData(0xe802, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
  static const IconData settings = const IconData(0xe803, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
  static const IconData feedback = const IconData(0xe804, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
  static const IconData format_list_bulleted = const IconData(0xe805, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
  static const IconData basket = const IconData(0xe806, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
  static const IconData roast_turkey = const IconData(0xe807, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
  static const IconData harvest = const IconData(0xe808, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
  static const IconData meat = const IconData(0xe809, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
  static const IconData carrot = const IconData(0xe80a, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
  static const IconData fish = const IconData(0xe80b, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
}
```

I'm looking for something like `Custom.allAttributes()` giving a list of all attributes of my class `Custom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
class Custom {


Custom._();

static const _kFontFam = "Custom";

var map =  { 


   "restaurant_menu" : IconData(0xe800, fontFamily: _kFontFam),
   "food" : IconData(0xe801, fontFamily: _kFontFam),
   "chart_line" : IconData(0xe802, fontFamily: _kFontFam),
   "settings" : IconData(0xe803, fontFamily: _kFontFam),
   "feedback" : IconData(0xe804, fontFamily: _kFontFam),
   "format_list_bulleted" : IconData(0xe805, fontFamily: _kFontFam),
   "basket" : IconData(0xe806, fontFamily: _kFontFam),
   "roast_turkey" : IconData(0xe807, fontFamily: _kFontFam),
   "harvest" : IconData(0xe808, fontFamily: _kFontFam),
   "meat" : IconData(0xe809, fontFamily: _kFontFam),
   "carrot" : IconData(0xe80a, fontFamily: _kFontFam),
   "fish" : IconData(0xe80b, fontFamily: _kFontFam)
}

Custom._allAttributes() { 
   map.toList();
 }


}


print(Custom._allAttributes());
```

Comment: I just tried your idea but I have an issue at the first line (_kFontFam : 'Custom';)

Comment: my bad, can you replace ";" with ","

Comment: tried too, the problem is now at the second line with the following problem : "The keys in a const map literal must be constant"

This file is generated when I add icons to my project, so I don't want to edit it if it's possible

Comment: I am trying in my environment, my flutter environment crashed, i have to restart that thing, i suppose as a final step you can remove the const keyword for the map. Instead of "var map = const {" do something like "var map = {"

reference: https://learningflutter.net/dart-fundamentals/
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_generics.htm

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to edit the file custom_icons.dart because each time I add an icon, the file is regenerated.